# JQuery Ajax live search on two fields - input and select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm able to get jQuery AJAX live search working on an input field and it returns the desired result that I want. Now I want to do a compound search on two fields.

This is what I have but it is not working or returning any errors:

**Form**:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchName" id="searchName" placeholder="Search by name">

      <span class="input-group-addon">Class</span>
      <select name="current_class" id="current_class" class="form-control">

       ## I populate my list from the database using php
       <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT * from classes";

               if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
                   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                       echo "<option value=\"{$row['class_id']}\"
                            {$row['class_name']} </option>";
                       }
                    }
               }
         ?>
      </select>
    </div>

   ##results are displayed
   <div id="result"></div>
   <div>
```

**Script**:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#searchName').keyup(function(){
            var name = $('#searchName').val();
            var current_class = $('#current_class').val();
          if (name != '' || current_class != '') {
             $.ajax({
                url:"fetch2.php",
                method:"post",
                data:{searchName:name, current_class:current_class},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
            });
         } else {
            $("#result").html('');
         }   
      });

      $('#current_class').keyup(function(){
            var name = $('#searchName').val();
            var current_class = $('#current_class').val();
          if (name != '' || current_class != '') {
             $.ajax({
                url:"fetch2.php",
                method:"post",
                data:{searchName:name, current_class:current_class},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
            });
         } else {
            $("#result").html('');
         }   
      });
    });
</script>
```

**Query in fetch2.php**:

```
$search_name = $_POST['searchName'];
$search_class = $_POST['current_class'];

$select__args = array();
$from__args = array();
$where__args = array("1=1");

$select__args[] = "student_id";
$from__args[] = "students";
$where__args[] = "(CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname) LIKE '%{$search_name}%')";

if($search_class != ''){
    $where__args[] = "current_class_id like '%{$search_class}%'";
}

$select_clause = implode(", ", $select__args);
$from_clause = implode(",", $from__args);
$where_clause = "(" . implode(") AND (", $where__args) . ")";

$query = "SELECT {$select_clause} FROM {$from_clause} WHERE {$where_clause}";
```

What am I missing here? What I want is a live search to be done on both fields either by name or by class. If there are two(2) students with the name: 'Nathan Siafa' but are in two(2) different classes(Grade 1 and 2) I will have to search by both name and class. Which is not the result I'm getting.

**UPDATE**

I have changed my code to match @maksbd19's answer. It works a little for me but I'm not getting the desired result that I want (live search experience on the two fields). I have just realized there maybe other problems. Ex. If there are two students - **John Amos Doe** and **John James Doe** with classes (grade 9 and 10). I realized that if a search is done for John Amos Doe whose class is grade 9 it works fine and returns the right record, but if I now want the record of John James Doe whose class is grade 10 I get the record of John Amos Doe (Note: my query searches by last name and first name).

I added a separate field to distinguish between the records. Now with @maksbd19 if I want John James Doe record and search is "John Doe" I still get "John Amos Doe" record even if I add the class for "John James Doe" in the class field it remains the same.

The way I get the precise record is by having the right class for "John James Doe" in placed and pretending to delete my current search value "John Doe" and it works. To me it's like ajax is only live searching on the name field.

*Note*: middle name is not require in my application that is why I'm not trying to perform a query on it, but is there a way that I can leverage the power of searching by a student full name(first, middle, last) even though not all student will have a middle name?

**Update 2**

I have manage to get the live search working the two(2) fields, based on the code I have here. My problem now is I have two(2) students in my tables - 'John Amos Doe(grade 10)' and 'John Lewis Doe(grade 9)'. If I search by first name with their specific classes it returns the desired result.

If I search 'John Doe' It brings 'John Amos Doe' record for example, and if I now want 'John Lewis Doe' record I have to put in the precise class (grade 9) in the class field which returns nothing.

I also tried to include the middle name in my search query but to no avail.
Here is how I tried:

```
$where__args[] = "(CONCAT(first_name,' ',middle_name,' ',surname) LIKE '%{$search_name}%') OR (CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname) LIKE '%{$search_name}%')";
```

Comment: Are you using the same code you've posted here? If so I just saw an error in your code. `if($search_id != ''){ $where__args[] = "current_class_id like '%{$search_class}%'"; }` check this part. I think `$search_id` should be `$search_class`. And also you should not use `like` instead use equality check operator.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have just updated the code. What happened was that I was running a separate test based on your answer to search by id. I taught another unique way could be to search by id. Nevertheless I'm facing the same problems.

Comment: If you still have problem then we can talk in the chatroom.

Comment: @maksbd19 can you link me to the specific chatroom? Also I've made some progress and have updated my post. Can you please take a look?

Comment: I just tested your code myself and searched for `John Lews Doe`. But I got results as expected. I've prepared a gist for you. Please let me know if I was doing any wrong.  https://gist.github.com/maksbd19/cdb466fc7103efee1b8a7648ea153064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken then you are getting the result as expected. Let me explain.

In your form the ajax function is okay, its just transferring the values in the server and getting back the query result. I think you need to refine your mysql query.

In your query there are three `OR` conditions for which the result would return anything matched by anything.

```
  student_id      current_class_id       first_name          last_name
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     1         |          1          |       Emma       |       Stone
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     2         |          1          |       Emma       |       Roberts
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     3         |          2          |       Emma       |       Watson
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     4         |          3          |       Julia      |       Roberts
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     5         |          3          |       Jane       |       Smith
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     6         |          1          |       John       |       Roberts
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
```

Lets examine this sample data.

Assume you typed `Jane` in the name field with no class id selected. Your mysql query will look for student id which would match the name you typed with **concatenated first_name and last_name**, **last_name**. Since you already concatenated both names you can omit the last one or keep both separated.

```
$query = "SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname) LIKE '%{$search_name}%'";
```

**OR**

```
$query = "SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE first_name LIKE '%{$search_name}%' OR surname LIKE '{%$search_name}%'"
```

Use either, both would yield same result.

*Note:* If you wanted to search for `Emma Roberts` then the query might be as following-

```
$query = "SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname) LIKE '%{$search_name}%' OR first_name LIKE '%{$search_name}%' OR surname LIKE '{%$search_name}%'"
```

In this way you can tell mysql to match first, last or whole name with the database.

Lets search for *Emma* (case sensitive)

```
  student_id      current_class_id       first_name          last_name
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     1         |          1          |       Emma       |       Stone
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     2         |          1          |       Emma       |       Roberts
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     3         |          2          |       Emma       |       Watson
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
```

And *Roberts*

```
  student_id      current_class_id       first_name          last_name
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     2         |          1          |       Emma       |       Roberts
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     4         |          3          |       Julia      |       Roberts
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     6         |          1          |       John       |       Roberts
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
```

And *Emma Roberts*

```
  student_id      current_class_id       first_name          last_name
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
     2         |          1          |       Emma       |       Roberts
---------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------
```

Now lets come to the second clause, the `current_class_id` part. I believe you would want an `AND` operation here. Because *search for Emma or students from class_id 1* doesn't make any sense. This search should be *search for Emma from students of class_id 1*

```
$query = "SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE current_class_id like '%{$search_class}%'";
```

Now lets combine this to achieve you was intended.

```
$query = "SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE (CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname) LIKE '%{$search_name}%' OR first_name LIKE '%{$search_name}%' OR surname LIKE '{%$search_name}%') AND current_class_id like '%{$search_class}%'";
```

This is basically telling mysql to look for Emma in both first_name and surname columns AND also associated with a specific current_class_id.

**Note**

The query sample above has a little glitch. If you don't include a `current_class_id` in the param, the query should omit it as well. In my case these types of filters generally accept lots of parameters. I like to split in in different parts.

```
$select_clause = implode(", ", $select__args);
$from_clause = implode(",", $from__args);
$where_clause = "(" . implode(") AND (", $where__args) . ")";
$query = "SELECT {$select_clause} FROM {$from_clause} WHERE {$where_clause}";
```

And then based on the parameters I provide to the filter script these clauses are populated accordingly. In your case you can have like the following-

```
$select__args = array();
$from__args = array();
$where__args = array("1=1"); // this is necessary because when this array is going to be imploded then if the array is empty there will be empty string, so mysql would return no result.

$search_name = $_POST['searchName']; // please escape, by all means...
$search_class = $_POST['current_class']; // please escape, by all means...

$select__args[] = "student_id";
$from__args[] = "students";
$where__args[] = "(CONCAT(first_name,' ',surname) LIKE '%{$search_name}%' OR
```

first_name LIKE '%{$search_name}%' OR surname LIKE '{%$search_name}%')";

```
if( $search_class != '' ){
    $where__args[] = "current_class_id like '%{$search_class}%'";
}
```

In this way I have control of joining tables, selecting columns and change condition based on the parameters.

Comment: thanks for the attention. I have just updated my question based upon the answer you've given. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @maksb19 Thanks for the effort. Got it done by the grace of God and  through your help.

Comment: could you describe a bit about what were you doing wrong? Just for reference for people who might have similar problem

Comment: The problem somehow was with a record in the table. Ex. 'John Lewis Doe' that I wanted. I realize that it was the only record of that kind giving the problem. But now, here is the catch if I search 'John  '/ John plus double spaces the record shows. If I search the middle name 'Lewis' it shows also. But if I search 'John Lewis Morris' it returns no record. I can't figure out what the problem was, but I'm still search my app to find the bug.